# Many to Many получение всех данных в одной строке

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many

имеется 3 таблицы: ads,keyskills_to_ads, key_skills.
keyskills_to_ads
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

key_skills
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
ads
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
SELECT `ads`.id AS id, kk.content AS skills FROM `ads` INNER JOIN `keyskills_to_ads` AS k ON `ads`.id = k.ads_id INNER JOIN `key_skills` AS kk ON kk.id = k.key_skill_id
```

И в ответ выдается несколько строк
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но как мне получить ответ в виде одной строки где в поле skills будет перечислять через запятую все связанные ключевые навыки, то есть "C++, C#"?
БД Mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL 8.0

Я не смог проверить ваш `SELECT...`, потому что вы не предоставили минимально воспроизводимый пример в SQL.

Вот решение используя CTE и метод `GROUP_CONCAT()`.

**SQL**

```
WITH cte (id, skills) AS (
    SELECT `ads`.id AS id, kk.content AS skills 
    FROM `ads` INNER JOIN `keyskills_to_ads` AS k ON `ads`.id = k.ads_id 
    INNER JOIN `key_skills` AS kk ON kk.id = k.key_skill_id
) 
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(skills ORDER BY skills ASC SEPARATOR ', ') AS skillList
FROM cte GROUP BY id;
```